# Improve R Script execution from NodeJS

Tags: r, node.js, machine-learning, raspberry-pi

I'm new to R, and I'm invoking an R script from a NodeJS app. When the R Script is invoked, it takes a long time in producing output. I investigated and realized that the bulk of that overhead is when it loads the libraries and the model I'm using. Let me clarify that any optimization would work, taking into account that I'm running this code in a Raspberry Pi 2 b+.

My question is: Is there a way to preload all the libraries and the model on R and then trigger predictions on demand? So that I won't need to reload the libraries and the model every time I want a prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Since you're just invoking a script the loading of everything it has to be done everytime the script is run; since nothing didn't exist in memory before you invoked it.

One workaround I would suggest is to instead run a R script have your R script running as a service and then query that service from `nodejs`.

I cannot help you with that since my expertise for R doesn't go very far away and I don't know if having an R server is even possible.

An alternative to that, if it is not too cumbersome, is to port your R project to `python` and mount a server of some kind (which with python is extremely easy to do) and then poke that server from `nodejs`. Since you would be running a server you can just cache the libraries at the server startup time and have everything in RAM for your next query.